# OpenStack - Neutron installation issue - Can't contact endpoint :9696

Tags: openstack, endpoint, openstack-neutron

I am a newbie and this is my first OpenStack installation... But I have a big issue with the neutron service. I can't contact endpoint on the controller ( IP:9696 ) but service are up. So in the web interface, on the network section I have these messages : 
1) Error: Unable to check if network availability zone extension is supported 2) Error: Unable to check if DHCP agent scheduler extension is supported 
3) Error: Network list can not be retrieved.

I follow very carefully the documentation, but I can't understand the source of the problem... Here are my logs:

/var/log/neutron/neutron-server.log

```
2018-06-06 06:25:23.755 6767 INFO neutron.common.config [-] Logging enabled!
2018-06-06 06:25:23.757 6767 INFO neutron.common.config [-] /usr/bin/neutron-server version 12.0.1
2018-06-06 06:25:23.759 6767 INFO neutron.common.config [-] Logging enabled!
2018-06-06 06:25:23.759 6767 INFO neutron.common.config [-] /usr/bin/neutron-server version 12.0.1
2018-06-06 06:25:23.956 6767 INFO keyring.backend [-] Loading Windows (alt)
2018-06-06 06:25:23.980 6767 INFO keyring.backend [-] Loading pyfs
2018-06-06 06:25:23.983 6767 INFO keyring.backend [-] Loading multi
2018-06-06 06:25:23.984 6767 INFO keyring.backend [-] Loading Google
2018-06-06 06:25:23.987 6767 INFO keyring.backend [-] Loading Gnome
2018-06-06 06:25:24.007 6767 INFO keyring.backend [-] Loading keyczar
2018-06-06 06:25:24.008 6767 INFO keyring.backend [-] Loading file
2018-06-06 06:25:24.258 6767 INFO neutron.manager [-] Loading core plugin: ml2
2018-06-06 06:25:25.136 6767 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.managers [-] Configured type driver names: []
2018-06-06 06:25:25.138 6767 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.managers [-] Loaded type driver names: []
2018-06-06 06:25:25.140 6767 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.managers [-] Registered types: []
2018-06-06 06:25:25.140 6767 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.managers [-] No type driver for tenant network_type: local. Service terminated!
```

/var/log/neutron/neutron-linuxbridge-agent.log

```
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent [-] Failed reporting state!: MessagingTimeout: Timed out$
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/plugins$
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     True)
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/agent/r$
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     return method(context, 'report_state', **kwargs)
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/$
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     retry=self.retry)
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/$
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     timeout=timeout, retry=retry)
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/$
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     retry=retry)
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/$
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     result = self._waiter.wait(msg_id, timeout)
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/$
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     message = self.waiters.get(msg_id, timeout=timeout)
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/$
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent     'to message ID %s' % msg_id)
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent MessagingTimeout: Timed out waiting for a reply to messa$
2018-06-06 06:25:19.762 2276 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent
2018-06-06 06:25:19.765 2276 WARNING oslo.service.loopingcall [-] Function 'neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.agent._common_agent.CommonAgentLoop$
```

/var/log/neutron/neutron-metadata-agent.log

```
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent [-] Failed reporting state!: MessagingTimeout: Timed out waiting for a repl$
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/agent/metadata/agent.py", $
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent     use_call=self.agent_state.get('start_flag'))
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutron/agent/rpc.py", line 93, in$
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent     return method(context, 'report_state', **kwargs)
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/client.py", lin$
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent     retry=self.retry)
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/transport.py", line$
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent     timeout=timeout, retry=retry)
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver$
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent     retry=retry)
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver$
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent     result = self._waiter.wait(msg_id, timeout)
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver$
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent     message = self.waiters.get(msg_id, timeout=timeout)
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver$
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent     'to message ID %s' % msg_id)
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent MessagingTimeout: Timed out waiting for a reply to message ID aba6414ea2d34$
2018-06-06 06:25:46.934 2234 ERROR neutron.agent.metadata.agent
2018-06-06 06:25:46.936 2234 WARNING oslo.service.loopingcall [-] Function 'neutron.agent.metadata.agent.UnixDomainMetadataProxy._report_st$
```

After two week of research, I am desperate... Please could you help me?

Comment: Sounds like you have an invalid option somewhere. Most likely the type_driver is set to local, but should most likely be set to flat
https://github.com/openstack/neutron/blob/55167835207e2affde8d088b97968e9b792357e1/doc/source/admin/deploy-ovs-provider.rst

Comment: Thank you @eandersson I found one part of the solution, this is a bad syntax for the transport_url in the /etc/neutron/neutron.conf file

Comment: I see - btw you are probably better of asking the same questions over IRC, or even here https://ask.openstack.org/en/questions/